Getting the module and class of currently executing classmethod in Python
For code that exists in a module named some.module and looks like this:
class MyClass:

 @classmethod
 def method(cls):
  # do something
  pass

I'd like to know in the block marked as "do something" what the module name, the class name, and the method name are. In the above example, that would be:

module some.module
class MyClass
method method

I know of inspect.stack() and I can get the function / method name from it, but I can't find the rest of the data.

These are the most direct ways:
import inspect

class MyClass:

 @classmethod
 def method(cls):
  print("module:", __name__)
  print("class:", cls.__name__)
  print("method:", inspect.currentframe().f_code.co_name)

Doing the same from a utility function requires traversing "back" (up) in the call stack to find the calling frame:
import inspect

def dbg():
    frame = inspect.currentframe().f_back
    print("module:", frame.f_globals.get("__name__"))
    print("cls:", frame.f_locals.get("cls"))
    print("method:", frame.f_code.co_name)


note that if you have class B(MyClass) and you call B().method(), then it will return B, not MyClass — but the module will still return the module containing MyClass (not that of B). Not sure whether this is intended behaviour

Is it possible to do all of that from inspecting a frame, so that a function called at "do something" can get this information about its caller?

@IvanVoras Yes. The logging framework actually does very similar - take a look at logging.getLogger().findCaller().

@tbrugere Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/79123294/674039 for an approach to get the definition location.
